# How to create a responsive layout in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In google material framework, I have this code

```
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3-desktop mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-tablet mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-phone">
            <v-text-field :type="page.text_input_date_from.type" :label="page.text_input_date_from.label" box autofocus :append-icon="page.text_input_date_from.icon" v-model="page.text_input_date_from.value"></v-text-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3-desktop mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-tablet mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-phone">
            <v-text-field :type="page.text_input_date_to.type" :label="page.text_input_date_to.label" box autofocus :append-icon="page.text_input_date_to.icon" v-model="page.text_input_date_to.value"></v-text-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3-desktop mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-tablet mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-phone">
            <v-text-field :type="page.text_input_person_name.type" :label="page.text_input_person_name.label" box autofocus :append-icon="page.text_input_person_name.icon" v-model="page.text_input_person_name.value"></v-text-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3-desktop mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-tablet mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-4-phone">
            <v-text-field :type="page.text_input_company_name.type" :label="page.text_input_company_name.label" box autofocus :append-icon="page.text_input_company_name.icon" v-model="page.text_input_company_name.value"></v-text-field>
        </div>
```

Basically there is classes like this

```
mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3
mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3-desktop
mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3-tablet
mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3-phone
```

How can I replicate the same thing using vuetify?

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid

I can't see any examples of responsive.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Vuetify Grid](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid) documentation page:

> It contains 5 types of media breakpoints that are used for targeting specific screen sizes or orientations. The props for grid components are actually classes that are derived from their defined properties.

Which means that props that are passed to `v-col` component define responsive classes for the grid element.

If you go to `#API` section on the same page and select `v-col` from component's select, the first available prop: `{size}="{1-12}` lists possible values to specify layout for each breakpoint:

> xs: extra small,
>     sm: small,
>     md: medium,
>     lg: large,
>     xl: extra large

And they are used with values of `1 through 12`.

Usage example:

```
<v-col 
  xs="12" 
  sm="5" 
  md="3"
>
  <v-card dark color="primary">
    ...
  </v-card>
</v-col>
```

Make sure to check `v-col` documentation for required layout structure for grid to work.